# How can I make it so that my action listener classes use the same int count variable?

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I am creating a simple GUI with an increment and reset JButton and a JTextField that outputs the counting number. The layout of the GUI is fine but I am having trouble with implementing my action listeners, here is where I create my buttons and assign the associated action listener to the variable:

```
        JTextField t = new JTextField(40);
        t.setText("Button Clicked " + 0 + " times");

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Increment");
        b1.addActionListener(new Incrementer(t));

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Reset");
        b2.addActionListener(new Reset(t));
```

This is in a class along with the other layout specifications. Here is my incrementer class which should increment the counter by 1:

```
class Incrementer implements ActionListener {
    JTextField t = new JTextField();

    public Incrementer (JTextField t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        t.getText();
        int numClicks = Integer.parseInt(t.getText());
        numClicks++;
        t.setText("Button Clicked " + numClicks + " times");
    }}
```

and my reset class which should reset the count to 0:

```
class Reset implements ActionListener {

JTextField t = new JTextField();
public int numClicks = 0;

public Reset (JTextField t) {
    this.t = t;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int numClicks = Integer.parseInt(t.getText());
    numClicks = 0;
    t.setText("Button Clicked " + numClicks + " times");
}}
```

I originally was having an issue where each action listener had its own numClicks value, for example I would click the increment counter 3 times, then reset to 0 and when I clicked increment again it would resume the count at 4 rather than 1. After trying to fix that I now cannot even click my increment and reset buttons as I get a nasty list of errors such as: java.lang.NumberFormatException. I have tried to work out what is wrong with my code but cannot find out what that is.

Comment: What values do the textfields hold initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a text field (which basically is a string) for working on a count value is not a good design approach. The exception you get is a consequence of the text you are storing in the text field: "Button Clicked x times". This is not a number.

So better use a separate *model*. You could add a new class for counting:

```
class Counter {
    private int count;
    int getCount() { return count; }
    void increment() { count += 1; }
    void reset() { count = 0; }
    // maybe some more methods ...
}
```

Now in your GUI class you do:

```
Counter counter = new Counter();

JTextField t = new JTextField(40);
t.setText("Button Clicked " + 0 + " times");

JButton b1 = new JButton("Increment");
b1.addActionListener(new Incrementer(counter, t));

JButton b2 = new JButton("Reset");
b2.addActionListener(new Reset(counter, t));
```

See that the action listeners get the *same* reference to one counter. Obviously you must then design your action listeners this way:

```
class Incrementer implements ActionListener {
    private final Counter counter;
    private final JTextField textfield;
    Incrementer(Counter counter, JTextField textfield) {
        this.counter = counter;
        this.textfield = textfield;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        counter.increment();
        textfield.setText("Button Clicked " + counter.getCount() + " times");
    }
}
```

The `Reset` class looks analogue. This is a bit like [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: it's very good answer but i have a simple question i.e how can you access `JTextField t` inside actionPerformed of Incrementer class ?